# How to apply Wasserstein distance measure on a group basis in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
     p         q    match
0.0116  0.009367    False
0.0100  0.009367    True
0.0065  0.009367    True
0.0072  0.006000    False
0.0048  0.006000    True
```

Here, p and q are two hypothetical distributions of vote shares of candidates in a constituency. Constituency starts when the `match` value is `False` and ends just before the next `False` value in the `match` column. So, for instance, the first three rows in the data frame belong to the first constituency, the next two belong to the second constituency and so on. I want to apply the [Wasserstein distance metric](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.wasserstein_distance.html) on the two distributions of each constituency. For instance, I would want to convert the first 3 entries for p and q into an array, apply Wasserstein distance and get a value. I would do the same for the next 2 rows so that finally my data frame would look something like this:

```
     p        q     match      wasserstein_dist
0.0116  0.009367    False
0.0100  0.009367    True
0.0065  0.009367    True           <some_value>
0.0072  0.006000    False
0.0048  0.006000    True           <some_value>
```

I tried using a for loop on p and q to convert them into arrays but then how do I apply the metric and get the answer above?

Note: There will be different number of candidates in different constituencies and hence different number of rows for each constituency.

Comment: is it always one false and consecutive trues to define one segment? or what is the logic for the different number of candidates?

Comment: Yes, one false and consecutive trues to define one segment, always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a `grp` column to group your data and then compute the distance:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as stats 

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'p': [  0.0116,   0.0100,   0.0065, 0.0072, 0.0048],
        'q': [0.009367, 0.009367, 0.009367, 0.0060, 0.0060],
        'match':[ False, True, True, False, True]
        })

df['grp'] = (-df['match']).cumsum()

ws_df = df.groupby('grp').apply(lambda x: stats.wasserstein_distance(x['p'], x['q']))
ws_df = ws_df.reset_index().rename(columns={0:'wasserstein_dist'})

df = pd.merge(df, ws_df, on='grp').drop('grp', axis=1)

df
        p         q  match  wasserstein_dist
0  0.0116  0.009367  False          0.001911
1  0.0100  0.009367   True          0.001911
2  0.0065  0.009367   True          0.001911
3  0.0072  0.006000  False          0.001200
4  0.0048  0.006000   True          0.001200
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand your logic. A very neat solution indeed. I was in the process of making separate data frames for separate constituencies and then apply Wasserstein distance but your solution is MUCH more efficient and it works nicely.